# jquery toggle and scroll to view

Tags: jquery

when a link is at the bottom of the browser window and user click it to show some content, I would like the browser to scroll down so that the shown content is located at the top of the window to be visible. how to do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain javascript to do this.

Use **[scrolIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollIntoView)** function.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear. I meant that scrollIntoView goes to the position instantly. but I would like to create a sliding effect for the scrolling.

Comment: For that you can use the scrollto plugin suggested by @Jon, or use animate function in jquery.

Comment: @perlwe & @rahul: You also have to think about the user experience here. If you page is long enough, *jumping* to some bottom element may be confusing for the user. Animated scrolling may be a better solution so user actually know what happened. I described the problem in my [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) (also providing a scrollintoview() jQuery plugin). I think that @Jon Erickson's answer is a better solution in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the jQuery [scrollto](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin

Comment: A similar but simpler (thus faster) plugin: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html

Comment: The `scrollintoview()` plugin also works without specifying the scrollable parent. It finds it for you. All you have to provide is just the element that you want to see. That's also the main difference from `scrollTo()` plugin which always works off the scrollable element.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `scrollTo()` ([link](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)) plugin there's also `scrollintoview()`([link](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html)) plugin.

They both animate scrolling but the first one requires at least **two** elements:

1. scrollable and
2. child

while the latter only requires you run it on the element that you want to be seen. It then automatically finds the nearest scrollable parent and scrolls it accordingly.