# Scroll toggled section into view w/ twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, toggle

I am building a site with twitter bootstrap. I have created a learnmore button at the bottom of my page that, when user clicks, toggles a div. I would like to have the window "scrollintoview" to show the div after the section expands.

The the learnmorebutton toggles the div properly, but the window does not scroll to show the div.

I have tried delaying the scrollintoview because if I just do onclick:scrollintoview without delay I can see the window wants to scroll down except the content isn't visible yet.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<div id="learnmorebtn">
<div class="learnmorebutton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#learnmore"  onclick="setTimeout('function () {"document.getElementById('learnmore').scrollIntoView()" }', 1500)"></button>
</div><!-- /#learnmorebtn -->

<div id="learnmore" class="collapse">my content</div><!-- /#learnmore -->
```

A live example of the issue I'm having (without the set timeout code) is at http://www.chasedutton.com/fqbootstrap/.

I've found this thread [jquery toggle and scroll to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197745/jquery-toggle-and-scroll-to-view) however I'm not sure how to integrate scrollto or scrollintoview after the toggle.

Thanks for your time, effort, and knowledge!